# What does "Set Glimpse Session Name" do?

Tags: glimpse

For such a big honkin' button on the main Glimpse control panel, it's surprising that "Set Glimpse Session Name" brings up only 7 results on Google (13 if you drop "Set").

Whatever it is, it sounds important. So what is a session name in Glimpse, and what does setting one do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `javascript:(function(){document.cookie='glimpseId='+ prompt('Client Name?') +';path=/;expires=Sat, 01 Jan 2050 12:00:00 GMT;';window.location.reload();})();`, that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Session name can help you to make a distinction between different clients. By default the browser name is used, but if you want to make distinction between different sessions in the same browser, then setting the session name will help you with that.

The printscreen I included will show you the different clients that were connected through the History tab, all requests are grouped per client. The *IE 10.0* or *Chrome 28.0* are defaults determined from the browser being used. The *cgijbels* is the one I set myself while using the same browser that initially indicated *Chrome 28.0*

I hope that answers your question

[image: Glimpse session name usage]